# Origin of "Knee-jerk"

Tags: etymology, metaphors

I like to read the Economist to keep my English up to date. And today, reading the following [news](http://www.economist.com/blogs/charlemagne/2013/02/spanish-politics) I came across the above mentioned expression.

Merriam Webster defines it as:

> reacting in a readily predictable way

I'd like to know how come such words like `knee` and `jerk` could come up with such a definition.

Comment: Did you ever swing your leg off the end of a chair or table and then hit it just below the kneecap?

Comment: What @Jim said. Surely this is General Reference / common knowledge?

Comment: Seems General Reference from [etymology dictionary](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=knee-jerk&allowed_in_frame=0).

Comment: Yes, the reference from the etymology dictionary is self evident to anyone who understands "the figurative use appeared soon after the phrase was coined". But I suppose to "coin a phrase" is General Reference also!

Comment: Should I delete the question? or perhaps get it moved to ELL.

Answer (score 4):

The phrase is metaphoric and is derived from the standard reflexive movement of the leg when the knee is struck in a certain way. [Oxford](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/knee-jerk?q=knee-jerk) defines it as

> *adjective* - (of a response) automatic and unthinking: *a knee-jerk reaction*
>    (of a person) responding to situations in an automatic and unthinking way: *knee-jerk radicals*
>    *noun* - 
>   a sudden involuntary reflex kick caused by a blow on the tendon just below the knee.

Answer (score 4):

A knee-jerk reaction is a reflex to an impact. If you have had a physical exam where the doctor checked your reflexes by tapping your knee cap with a little rubber hammer, then you've seen a true knee-jerk reaction.